# How to use subdomain like user.test.com in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, subdomain

How to use subdomain like user.test.com in IIS 7. Suppose we have main domain test.com.
I want that when we call user.test.com IIS will use test.com domain. And subdomains may be a lot of amount.

Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create new Site/Application in IIS management console.

Click on newly created site and in Actions/Edit site/Bindings... Bindings dialog will be opened. There you can define as subdomain URL for you site. Click 'Add' and put user.domain.com as your host name;

Comment: Thank you so much! It resolved all my problems!!! I've spent whole day yesterday to figure out where is the problem! Thank you again!